# What can I do when template column shows undefined?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was trying to work on a .Net 4.0 project + FineUI, but I got error like this "template column shows undefined". Plus the data in my table is misplaced. Can somebody help? Here's my sample code:

```
<ext:PageManager ID="PageManager1" AutoSizePanelID="Grid1" runat="server" />
<ext:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BodyPadding="0px" EnableBackgroundColor="true"
    ShowBorder="false" ShowHeader="false" Title="Panel">
    <Items>
        <ext:Grid ID="Grid1" Title="Answered Question" AutoWidth="true" AutoScroll="true" ShowBorder="true"
            ShowHeader="true" AllowSorting="true" AutoHeight="true" PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true"
            runat="server" EnableCheckBoxSelect="false" DataKeyNames="SYSID" IsDatabasePaging="true"
            EnableRowNumber="false">
            <Toolbars>
                <ext:Toolbar ID="Toolbar1" Position="Top" runat="server">
                    <Items>
                        <ext:ToolbarFill ID="ToolbarFill1" runat="server">
                        </ext:ToolbarFill>
                        <ext:TwinTriggerBox runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="250px" EmptyText="Input Question Name"
                            ShowLabel="false" ID="TwinTriggerBox1" ShowTrigger1="false" Trigger1Icon="Clear"
                            Trigger2Icon="Search" OnTrigger1Click="TwinTriggerBox1_Trigger1Click"     OnTrigger2Click="TwinTriggerBox1_Trigger2Click">
                        </ext:TwinTriggerBox>
                    </Items>
                </ext:Toolbar>
            </Toolbars>

        </ext:Grid>
    </Items>
</ext:Panel>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so, especially [ask] and [mcve], before posting your next question here.

Answer (score 0):

Add the controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion and clientIDMode properties for the  tag of  in Web.config

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="FineUI" namespace="FineUI" tagPrefix="f" />
      </controls>
</pages>
```